# Python & SWIG: Using StringIO in place of FILE*

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have the following method which I wrap using SWIG to access it in Python:

```
void some_class::some_method( FILE *fp, int *pT, int **pO ) {
    fscanf( fp, "lalala", pT );
```

How is it possible to pass a StringIO for the first argument? What typemap should I use?

Comment: Sanity check: you're just reading from the `FILE*` not writing to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to construct a typemap that uses `fmemopen` to automatically create a `FILE*` for you. I created an example:

```
%module test
%include <typemaps.i>

%typemap(in) FILE *sb (PyObject *str=NULL) {
  str = PyObject_CallMethod($input, "getvalue", NULL);
  char *buf = NULL;
  int len = 0;
  PyString_AsStringAndSize(str, &buf, &len);
  $1 = fmemopen(buf, len, "r");
}

%typemap(freearg) FILE *sb {
  if ($1) fclose($1);
  Py_XDECREF(str$argnum);
}

%apply int *OUTPUT { int * i };

%inline %{
  void foo(FILE *sb, int *i) {
    fscanf(sb, "%d", i);
  }
%}
```

There are two parts to this, firstly there's some python C API to call `getvalue` on the `StringIO` in order to get access to the data it holds. This buffer needs to live for at least as long as the `FILE*`, so we have to introduce an extra variable and clean it up when we're done.

I also used `%apply` to automatically treat `int *i` as an output rather than input. This is probably sufficient to do what you're trying to do.

This was sufficient to allow me to run the following test program:

```
import StringIO
import test

buf=StringIO.StringIO("666")
print test.foo(buf)
```

If you want to make the interface more generic I'd suggest inserting a call to [`PyFile_AsFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/file.html) to handle Python File objects that really are files and not just StringIO objects. You can check the return value to try using the argument you're given as a number of different viable types of inputs.

This is pretty convoluted. The nicer solution would be to use [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) instead, which gives you a direct C API, avoiding the call to `getvalue` entirely. If you're using glibc then you can use [`fopencookie`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) to hook a `FILE*` directly to the `cStringIO` object for zero copy.